# Can not type anything in input field returned from a functional component to App.jsx in React.js

Tags: reactjs

Please do me a favour. What happen is that I am not able to type anything in the input fields

returned from a functional component to App.jsx in React.

I am trying to construct a user registration form which contains the fields of user's name,

email and phone number.
I returned three inputs of those like this;

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function Pages() {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState({
    name: "",
    email: "",
    phone: "",
  });

  function handleChange() {
    setMessage();
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        name="name"
        value={message.name}
        onChange={handleChange}
        type="text"
      />

      <input
        name="email"
        value={message.email}
        onChange={handleChange}
        type="text"
      />

      <input
        name="phone"
        value={message.phone}
        onChange={handleChange}
        type="text"
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Pages;
```

But When I type text in the input field, I found that I am not able to type anything in it.

So, Please advise me how to solve this problem and I have no idea to fix this.

Thank you

Aung

Comment: What are you expecting `setMessage()` with no arguments to do?

Answer (score 1):

This is how your handleChange should look like:

```
function handleChange(e) {
    setMessage((message) => {
        return {
            ...message,
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        }
    })
}
```

Your input will always have the value from your message.phone, message.email, etc... because you explicitly gave it to the input when you wrote value = {message.phone}, for instance

In order to change the message.phone, for instance, you use the handleChange function to update the state of the component, and, therefore, update the input tag. Notice how now, setMessage is giving it a new value, returning all that message already has and mutating e.target.name (phone) to e.target.value (whatever the user is typing).

Comment: There are slight problems with your code. You should wrap `{...message, e.target.name: e.target.value}` with `( )` because the syntax thinks you're creating the function body and not returning the new object with the code you provided. Also, wrap `e.target.name` with `[ ]` because the code provided also runs into a SyntaxError. Adding `[ ]` will tell JS to replace `e.target.name` to become the property's actual value.